# could not be translated and will be evaluated locally. EF CORE

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

The SQL `WHERE` clause is not being generated when using properties of my base class.

The following example is a basic version of the problem:

**Exception message**

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'where (new PackageViewModel() {CreatedByUserName = [p.CreatedBy].UserName, Id = [p].Id}.CreatedByUserName == "Ivan")' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    public String CreatedByUserName { get; set; }
}

public class PackageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class myTest
{
    public void Test()
    {   
       var query = _dbContext.Set<Package>().Select(p => new PackageViewModel()
        {
            CreatedByUserName = p.CreatedBy.UserName,
            Id = p.Id
        });

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(PackageViewModel), "p");
        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<PackageViewModel, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(param, "CreatedByUserName"),
                Expression.Constant("Ivan", typeof(String))
            ), param
        );

        var result = query.Where(exp).ToList();
    }
}
```

If I try with:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(BaseViewModel), "p");
```

It works, but then it doesn't work with other properties like `Id`, because they doesn't exist in the base class.

The problem is that in my final version I have some dynamic `where`’s over properties that are in my main class and others that are in my base class; which will result in something like this : `( p => p.Id == "…" && p.CreatedByUserName == "…")`

**Questions**

Is this a bug?

Why do properties that are in my base class only evaluate locally?

Is there a workaround?

Is the solution to copy all properties from my base class to all my main classes?

**Further technical details**

EF Core version: 2.0.3

Database Provider: Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.0.1

Operating system:

IDE: Visual Studio 2017 15.7.2

Comment: Why don't you do the where before the select and compare `p.CreatedBy.UserName` to "Ivan"?  The idea is that you're suppose to deal with the Entities in your query up to the select where you can hydrate simple classes with the results.  This is because EF has to translate that to SQL which knows nothing of your view model.

Comment: Bug. Still not fixed even in 2.1 See the GitHub issue opened by the OP of the duplicate question under my answer. They just closed it :( May be you can vote to reopen it.

Comment: @IvanStoev they will fix in 2.2.0 https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12230#issuecomment-394437051

Comment: @juharr i can't do this : Expression.Property(param, "CreatedBy.UserName") :(

Comment: @IvanValadares Good. Will be waiting for it (as usual :)